# Implementing monoid for Reader

Tags: haskell, higher-kinded-types, monoids

I may be naive in my thinking here but I think if the right hand value of a `Reader` is an instance of `Monoid` then a `Monoid` could be defined for `Reader`... Here is my implementation:

```
instance Monoid a => Monoid (Reader r a) where
  mempty = pure mempty
  mappend ra rb = (<>) <$> ra <*> rb
```

This however results in the following error:

```
    • Illegal instance declaration for ‘Monoid (Reader r a)’
        (All instance types must be of the form (T t1 ... tn)
         where T is not a synonym.
         Use TypeSynonymInstances if you want to disable this.)
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Monoid (Reader r a)’
    |
413 | instance Monoid a => Monoid (Reader r a) where
    |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I am unsure what this error actually means, and why I am unable to implement `Monoid` for `Reader` though I presume it is something to do with `Reader` being a higher kinded type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems. The first is this:

```
type Reader r = ReaderT r Identity
```

For historical reasons, type synonyms are not allowed in instance declarations. This is the

```
where T is not a synonym.
```

part of the error. Luckily we can just expand the synonym; this would give us

```
instance Monoid a => Monoid (ReaderT r Identity a)
```

but now we would fall afowl of the other part of the error, namely:

```
All instance types must be of the form (T t1 ... tn)
```

Specifically, `Identity` is not a type variable, so it doesn't fit this form. Again this restriction is in place primarily for historical reasons. You can remove both restrictions by enabling two language extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
```

However, in this case it's not needed. The preferable way is to actually use the prescribed form of instance declaration, so:

```
instance (Applicative f, Monoid m) => Monoid (ReaderT r f m) where
    mempty = pure mempty
    mappend = liftA2 mappend
```

This requires no extensions, and works not just for `Reader` but for `ReaderT` transforming any `Applicative` instance.

However it does make an orphan instance; hence you should consider writing *another* newtype wrapper.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
-- or, instead of GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, write the obvious instances by hand
newtype App f m = App { getApp :: f m } deriving (Functor, Applicative)
instance (Applicative f, Monoid m) => Monoid (App f m) where
    mempty = pure mempty
    mappend = liftA2 mappend
```

Then you can use `App (Reader r) a` as a monoid whenever `a` is a monoid. I seem to recall this existed somewhere in the standard libraries already, but I can't find it any more...

Comment: It's called `Ap`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Ap

Comment: now it could be [derived via](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_via.html?highlight=derivingvia#extension-DerivingVia) `deriving (Semigroup, Monoid) via Ap (ReaderT r m) a`

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that your `Reader` is a type alias instead of a `newtype`.

Using the former is disallowed by Haskell2010 (which is very conservative in what it is allowed), but GHC allows using type aliases in instances if you turn on the extension reported in the error you posted. Note that in such case it would define an instance for the *expansion* of the alias, e.g.

```
instance Monoid a => Monoid (r -> a) where ...
```

For a `Reader` type, I'd prefer to use a newtype, even if one needs to wrap/unwrap it when it is used.